# What will be the complexity of the algorithm below

Tags: algorithm

I have a piece of code. I think the complexity of the code is O(n). But not sure, so can you please confirm me?

```
int low=0;
int high=array.length-1;

while(low<high)
    {
        while(array[low]!=0)
            low++;
        while(array[high]==0)
            high--;

        int temp=array[low];
        array[low++]=array[high];
        array[high--]=temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program keeps increasing low and decreasing high until they meets, so it's O(n)

Answer (score 2):

Your program appears to be a [Merge algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm), which is O(N) or linear time.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your program, the number of times you increment `low` plus the number of times you decrement `high` is going to be the length of the array, which is O(N).

A famous algorithm with a similar structure to this is the partition step in Quicksort. You might be able to find more detailed analysis if you search for that.

Answer (score 0):

O(n)

You can get confused with O(n^2) but as you can replace while with if conditions so then there will be no 2 loops, while loops are just put there to increase the computation.

you can also do like:

```
while(low<high)
{
    if(arr[low]!=0)
        low++;
    if(arr[high]==0)
        high--;
    //Rest of the things
}
```

Here clearly the complexity is O(n) and the code is exactly same. So your code is also O(n) complexity.

Answer (score -1):

Not necessarily
If everything in the {} is O(1) then yes it is O(n)

```
int low=0;
int high=array.length-1;
while(low<high)
{
}
```

If something in the {} was O(n) then it would be order n squared